# Upload a file from a Power Automate flow into a GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, power-automate, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file from an automatic power flow into a GCS bucket.

Since there is an action to make an HTTP request, I tried to use it; what I did is :

- creating a service account on GCP
- grant this service account the role of GCS object creator on the bucket
- create a p12 key
- inside the power automatic action: I chose the authentication mode "client credentials' ' and for the field PFX, I gave the output of my p12 file converted into base64 + I also gave the password associated with the p12 file.

But when I test the flow, I get a 401 unauthorized response saying that the Anonymous caller does not have the permission storage.objecy.create.

Is there anyone who has done something similar and could help me? Any ideas are welcome :-).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that your client, or any intermediate proxy, is not adding an Authorization header to requests to Cloud Storage. Any request with an Authorization header, even if empty, is validated as if it were an authentication attempt. This is the reason for the [401 authorization issue.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting)

**And also check below Unauthorized Reasons & Description**

**1. Authentication Required Requester Pays**

Access to a Requester Pays bucket requires authentication.

**2. AuthError**

This error indicates a problem with the authorization provided in the request to Cloud Storage. The following are some situations where that will occur:

- The OAuth access token has expired and needs to be refreshed. This can be avoided by refreshing the access token early, but code can also catch this error, refresh the token and retry automatically.
- Multiple non-matching authorizations were provided; choose one mode only.
- The OAuth access token's bound project does not match the project associated with the provided developer key.
- The Authorization header was of an unrecognized format or uses an unsupported credential type.

**3. lockedDomainExpired**

When downloading content from a cookie-authenticated site, e.g., using the [Storage Browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser), the response will redirect to a temporary domain. This error will occur if access to said domain occurs after the domain expires. Issue the original request again, and receive a new redirect.

**4. Required**

Access to a non-public method that requires authorization was made, but none was provided in the Authorization header or through other means.

[Refer to this doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes).